# Inverting the left axis of a LineChartView fills the chart on the wrong side

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I have the following chart that is supposed to represent top-10 positions of something:

[image]

I need to reverse the left axis though, since the top placement should be at the top. I do this with the following:

```
chartView.leftAxis.inverted = true
```

The problem is that I end up with this:

[image]

How can I keep the inverted chart with the gradient below the line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create this class:

```
class MyFillFormatter: IFillFormatter {

     func getFillLinePosition(dataSet: ILineChartDataSet, dataProvider: LineChartDataProvider) -> CGFloat
     {
         return CGFloat(dataSet.yMax)
     }

}
```

and then in your chart

```
chartView.leftAxis.inverted = true
chartView.rightAxis.inverted = true
set.fillFormatter = MyFillFormatter()
```

result: 
[image]